# Is (으)ㄴ/는단 a shortened form of (으)ㄴ/는다는?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning

i have a sentece as follows:

> 요즘 살을 빼기 때문에 밥을 안 먹고 과일만 먹어요.

> 정말 과일만 먹**는단** 말이에요?

Can i replace the 는단 in the sentence above with 는다는 to become like this?

> 정말 과일만 먹**는다는** 말이에요?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, it is simply a shortened form of 다는.

Comment: Thanks. So from that I can further deduce: (이)란 is a shortened form of (이)라는, (으)란 is a shortened form of  (으)라는 and 잔 is a shortened form of 자는, right?

Comment: Indeed, those work in a similar manner.